# Convert (UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh to Timezone name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I want to convert string in the format:
**(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh** to Timezone Name in rails. I am getting this value from an API and need to convert into usable format in rails.

Comment: The timezone in Rails can be found with `ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Riyadh"]` but its missing a UTC offset. Depending on the situation you might need to either search `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all` to try to find a match of use a 3d party API to lookup a valid offset.

Comment: Thanks, But can you explain how to find a match with `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all`?